Weird error using evolution mail (keyring-related?)
I use Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular) on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 (Gen12) with the standard Gnome shell (see here for my setup). The problem is not specific to oracular, it was present with 22.04 as well.
I am getting this weird error where after a restart, the mail client evolution does not connect to any of my email accounts (I get errors about "Timeout reached" popping up in my client, see screenshot below). I say it is weird, because it only happens sometimes and when I restart the computer the problem is usually gone (it happens maybe 50% of the time when I restart - it is very annoying!).

I think this issue might have something to do with the gnome keyring (when I login, I get a a popup telling me to unlock the keyring with a password, which I can succesfully complete).
I have no idea how to diagnose this problem (i.e., which logfiles to look at etc), any help would be very much appreciated!
